# How to set cookies for remember me checkbox after login in codeigniter?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

view:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#login").click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            elogin = $("#elogin").val();
            plogin = $("#plogin").val();
            remember_me = $("#remember_me").val();
            $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                data:{"elogin":elogin,"plogin":plogin,"remember_me":remember_me},
                url:"<?php echo base_url(); ?>login_redirect",
                success: function(data) {
                    if (typeof data !== 'object') {
                        data = JSON.parse(data);
                    }
                    if (data.redirect) 
                    {
                        window.location.replace(data.redirect);
                    } 
                    else 
                    {
                        $(".login_success").html('<p>' + data.error + '</p>');
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
<div class="login_success"></div>
<label class="control-label">Your Email</label>
<input class="form-control" placeholder="" type="email" id="elogin">

<label class="control-label">Your Password</label>
<input class="form-control" placeholder="" type="password" id="plogin">

<input name="optionsCheckboxes" id="remember_me" type="checkbox"> Remember Me
<button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary full-width" id="login">Login</button>
```

Controller:

```
public function login_redirect()
{
    $email = $this->input->post('elogin');
    $password = $this->input->post('plogin');
    $remember = $this->input->post('remember_me');

    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('user');
    $where = "email='".$email."' and password='".$password."' and status='1'";
    $this->db->where($where);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    if($query->num_rows() > 0) 
    {
        $result = $query->result_array();
        $this->session->set_userdata('user_id',$result);
        if (!isset($_POST)) 
        {
            header ("Location:".base_url()."thankyou");
        } 
        else 
        {
            echo json_encode(array('redirect' => base_url().'thankyou'));
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        echo json_encode(array('error' => 'Wrong email or password or may be your account not activated.'));
    }
}
```

In this code, I simply create a login form and do login via jquery ajax which is successfully working. Now, I want to set cookie after successful login via jquery ajax and cookie available only for one day after the day cookie expires. So, How can I do this? Please help me.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

**View Page - Login.php :**

```
 <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Enter Email"  value="<?php if(isset($_COOKIE["email"])) { echo $_COOKIE["email"]; } ?>" required>
<input type="checkbox" name="remember" <?php if(isset($_COOKIE["email"])) { ?> checked <?php } ?> > Remember Me
```

**Controller - LoginController.php**

```
$email = $this->input->post('email');
$password = md5($this->input->post('password'));
$remember = $this->input->post('remember');

if(!empty($remember)) {  
  setcookie ("email",$email,time()+ 3600);  
  setcookie ("password",$password,time()+ 3600);
}else{  
    if(isset($_COOKIE["email"] && isset($_COOKIE["password"])) ){  
        setcookie ("email",""); setcookie ("password","");   
    }  
}
```